# Return statement not executing

Tags: python

Hey guys so i have a problem and it is that my return statement is not executing.
This is my sudo code. It searches a tree to see if an item is in the tree.

```
def search(self, i):
    if left child is None and right child is None
        if self.data == i:
            return True
        else:
            pass 
    elif self.data == i:
        return True
    else:
        if left child exists:
            return self.left.search(i)
        if right child exists:
            return self.right.search(i)
```

The code seems to work except when `self.data == i`, the code does not run the return True statement even though the
if statement is executed. Does anyone know why this is?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: ADDED THE SELF PARAMETER. IT WAS SUPPOSED TO BE THERE, WAS A TYPO..

I inserted the numbers 3, 8, 2 and 1 into the tree and then searched for 1. I added a print statement if left child is None and right child is None: if self.data == i: print('self.data == i') return True I added that print statement when searching for 1 and the print statement did print which means that the if statement was executed, however, the return True statement does not execute

Comment: Unless you provide a use case, we can't tell what your problem is. My inclination is that either `i` or `self.data` is not what you think it is, so your conditional is evaluating to `False` when you don't think it is. Try making that `pass` a `return False` instead and see what you get.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Hm no, I inserted the numbers 3, 8, 2 and 1 into the tree and then searched for 1.
I added a print statement     
    if left child is None and right child is None:
        if self.data == i:
            print('self.data == i')
            return True

I added that print statement when searching for 1 and the print statement did print which means that the if statement was
executed, however, the return True statement does not execute.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you're trying to do a binary search, in which case you have some problems in your code. The return statement is probably not executed because the condition `self.data == i` fails. Also, note that if the root has a left child, the right child never gets looked at in your original code.

This is an implementation of a *linear* search, I'll leave it as an exercise to modify it to a binary search.

```
def search(self, i):
    if self.data == i:
        return True

    if self.left is not None:
        if self.left.search(i):
            return True
    if self.right is not None:
        return self.right.search(i)
    return False
```

Comment: Sorry about that, it was supposed to be there. It was a typo. Doesn't work even if I have it

Comment: Hm no, I inserted the numbers 3, 8, 2 and 1 into the tree and then searched for 1. I added a print statement if left child is None and right child is None: if self.data == i: print('self.data == i') return True I added that print statement when searching for 1 and the print statement did print which means that the if statement was executed, however, the return True statement does not execute

Comment: How are you verifying that the return statement doesn't execute?

Comment: because when I print(True), it prints "True". I know it actually goes into the if statement because I used a print('a') to check it. However, when I change print to return, it does not return "True"

Comment: You should use pdb to debug. The return statement is being executed if the message is printed. There is likely a mistake somewhere else. Have you tried using my code?